# sylius: site not deploying correctly in production

Tags: symfony, sylius

I've developed a sylius based site and all is working fine in development environment, but some problems have arisen when deploying it on the  production environment:

In Frontend: compiled frontend.js return an error:

> (function ($) { Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function frontend.js:27
>   (anonymous function)

jquery 1.8.0 is included before the line that produces the error.

In Backend: no errors seems to arise but select widgets doesn't render (none of them).

The steps done to deploy the site in prod were:

1. Migrated the database.
2. Installed in production environmnet:

   ```
   php app/console sylius:install -e prod
   ```
3. Cleared and warmed up the cache:

   ```
   php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
   php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
   ```
4. Dumped assets:

   ```
   php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
   ```

Curiously, when debug parameter is set to true in app.php none of these errors arise.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run Assetic dump command with the no-debug option. `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`.